# Make SharePoint Calendar Visible for Public

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar

I am trying to make a SharePoint calendar available for public viewing. Is there anyway to make this possible?

Comment: By "Public" do you mean everyone on the internet, or all your SharePoint Online users.

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan What I need is to make anyone on the internet able to view only a single calendar.

Comment: I can think of two ways to accomplish this.  Note that SharePoint Online sites are NOT meant to be public facing and Microsoft has pulled the ability to have public facing SharePoint Online sites.  
First you will need to create an anonymous access link to the calendar. depending on your settings in the admin center you may have to enable the ability to have anonymous access links.  Then you would either need to publish the link to the calendar on your existing public website, so anonymous users can find the link, or you might be able to display the calendar on your existing site in an iframe

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan Where would I start in trying to accomplish this?

Comment: See edit above ;)

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan Thank you very much! I will try this and let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, are you referring to a Calendar view for a SP List ? Generally speaking, view access needs to be managed manually. In other words, you need to add individuals you wish to grant access to into a group with read access.

I am not entirely sure if it is possible to publish a SP calendar to the public. From my understanding, doing so would defeat the purpose of including content on SharePoint since permission management is a big incentive for creating a SharePoint site.

Hope it helps!